# MVC EF String Length / Data Type for Signature Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using a javascript plugin called jSignature to give my MVC4 application delivery signature capture functionality.  jSignature outputs the signature info in a  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG... string format that looks to be around 32,000 characters long.  I created a property in my model called DeliverySignature as a string and am able to save and retrieve the signature data but when I pull it back in from the database it's only about 5,000 characters long.  What data type do I need to be using in my model's definition and in the action method (it's being passed in to a controller to save to the db) so that it preservers the complete string length?  Thank you.

Comment: Please, add code example for more info

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in `varchar(max)` column.
You can keep model property type of `string` as `strings` do not have a limited length.